# How to prevent the PC(Host)'s internet browser to use the 2nd wireless adapter used by VMs (Guests)?

Tags: windows, vmware, adapter, bridged

An intro must be provided so you could answer the question:

- On my Win10x64 PC (Host) I run lots of VMs (Guests) ;
- I've connected 2 wireless Adapters (A-A, A-B) to the Host which are connected to separate Routers, RA and RB (each one uses different ISP) ;
- The Guests must use only Adapter-B's connection and never Adapter-A's. So I've disabled "VMware Bridge protocol" on Adapter-A, and I've set all the VMs to use Bridged Connection. So they'll always use Adapter B, like I want.
- The Host must have both adapters enabled - Adapter-A for the "host's browser" and Adapter-B so the VMs can use it.

The question is how to make sure that the Host's internet browser in particular will use only Adapter-A and never Adapter-B (even if Adapter-A losts connection or disappears completely) ?

Comment: Please add an OS tag for your host OS; the answer will different e.g. for Linux vs. Windows.

Comment: @dirkt Done it, I totally forgot about that.